# Hide link title attribute based on screen width – won't unhide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made an attempt here based on some things I have gleaned, but this is just plain removing it altogether; the title doesn't return back at <= 768px

```
<script>
if( $(window).width() > 767) {

    $('[title]').each( function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title',$this.attr('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('title');

    });
}
</script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2nHxV/

Comment: The live demo doesn't include the width testing code…

Comment: _“the title doesn't return back at <= 768px”_ – and you expect that to happen magically by itself …?

Answer (score 1):

So put it back?

```
var $titles = [];

if( $(window).width()> 767) {
    $('[title]').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title',$this.attr('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('title');

        $titles.push($this);
    });
} else {
    $.each($titles, function(index, $this) {
        $this.attr('title',$this.data('title'));
    });
}
```

Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/z3rr9d04/

You also might want to put this logic inside a `$(window).on('resize', ...);` handler since it'll only be executed once on page load as it stands currently.

Comment: Of the two answers here I like that this one caches the element references and only traverses the DOM once.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    $('[title]').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title',$this.attr('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('title');
    });
} else {
    // as in above `title` attribute removed and `data-title` added, so now you've 
    // to loop with data-title 
    $('[data-title]').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title',$this.data('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('data-title');
    });
}
```